# How to replace remainder of sliced word with asterix?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a simple little script that takes a string, slices up to a specified character and replaces the remainder of the word with asterixes (*). Example below.

```
def multi_blank(strng, ch_count):
    """
    >>> multi_blank("banana", 1)
    'b*****'
    """
```

I always get into trouble when I'm trying to learn slicing and indexing. I managed to slice up to the specified number but am unable to figure out how to replace the remainder of the word with stars.

```
    return strng[:ch_count] + "*" + strng[ch_count:]
```

Above is what I have tried, but it returns the following:

```
Expected:
    'b*****'
Got:
    'b*anana'
```

I also tried:

```
    string = strng.replace(strng[ch_count:], '*')
    return string
```

Any help would be appreciated a long with a brief explanation of how it's done. Appreciate it!

Comment: Almost had it, just do `strng[:ch_count] + '*' * (len(strng) - ch_count)`, where `*` is replicated by the length minus `ch_count`.

Comment: You may use the fact that strings can be "multiplied" in Python. Find out how many stars you need, and prepare a string of that many starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are only appending a `*` after the sliced string, and then adding the rest of the string after it

```
In [22]: strng = 'banana'                                                                                                                                                           

In [24]: strng[:1] + "*" + strng[1:]                                                                                                                                                
Out[24]: 'b*anana'
```

So in order to create the rest of the string, you can use the overloaded multiplication  for string, by multiplying `*` by `(len(strng) - ch_count)` times (thanks @cs95 for the suggestion) and append it to the end of the sliced string

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

> The arguments must either both be numbers, or **one argument must be an integer and the other must be a sequence**. In the former case, the numbers are converted to a common type and then multiplied together. **In the latter case, sequence repetition is performed**; a negative repetition factor yields an empty sequence.

```
In [27]: strng = 'banana'                                                                                                                                                           

In [28]: strng[:1] + "*" * (len(strng)-1)                                                                                                                                           
Out[28]: 'b*****'
```

Hence the updated code will be

```
def multi_blank(strng, ch_count):
    """
    >>> multi_blank("banana", 1)
    'b*****'
    """
    return strng[:ch_count] + "*" * (len(strng) - ch_count)

print(multi_blank("banana", 1))
```

The output will be

```
b*****
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to the following code:

```
def multi_blank(string, ch_count):
    return string[:ch_count] + ("*"*len(string[ch_count:]))

print(multi_blank('banana',1))
```

Output:

```
b*****
>>>
```

Thanks to @cs95 for the suggestion for making code more efficient by omit unnecessary of generating sliced text before get the length of remaining text to be changed to asterisk. So the code is changed to be:

```
def multi_blank(string, ch_count):
    return string[:ch_count] + "*"*(len(string)-ch_count)

print(multi_blank('banana',1))
```

Comment: `len(strng[ch_count:])` does the unnecessary step of slicing the string before determining the length.

Comment: `>>> ch_count=1
>>> string='banana'
>>> len(string[ch_count:])`
Output : 5.

It's used to generate the length of remaining text to be changed to asterisk.

Comment: I understand that, but my point was you don't have to generate the text to find its length.